# Abstaining from meat and wine until shabbas Nachamu

Tags: meat, grapes-wine, nine-days, three-weeks

I remember seeing somewhere that there was a minhag not to eat meat or drink wine until shabbas nachamu. Where can I find this minhag mentioned?

Comment: that's שבוע שחל בו תשעה באב in the Gemara. It's a Machloket Tannaim if it's from Rosh Chodesh or the whole week. We're lenient both ways. Do you mean a modern Minhag?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.29b?lang=he

Comment: Meaning after tisha bav

Comment: Please clarify in your question when you mean this to start. The way it's currently phrased implies that one should begin today.

Answer (score 1):

I found this custom mentioned in the Shu"t Maharshal siman 54 . The custom was started by women who refrained from eating meat up until shabbas nachamu. The Maharshal noted that this custom is not mentioned anywhere and should not be continued.